# How to use Base64.getUrlEncoder in Android Lollipop

Tags: java, android, base64url

How can i get the same result of this method using a lower `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` in android:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
String result1 = "https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkijuZglD51udjvlclZWSNf_2wo";
String aa = Base64.getUrlEncoder()
                    .withoutPadding()
                    .encodeToString(result1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Output is this : https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL3UvcyFBa2lqdVpnbEQ1MXVkanZsY2xaV1NOZl8yd28/root/content

This code works fine but the issues is it requires android version oreo or higher but my application minimum sdk is *Lollipop* is it possible to get the same result but with a code that will work on lower version of android anything from *Lollipop* and above?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use [android.util.Base64](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64) `encodeToString(byte[] input, int flags)`

It has been available since Android 2.2.X Froyo/API level 8.

You would use it like:

```
android.util.Base64.encodeToString(YOUR_BYTE_ARRAY, android.util.Base64.URL_SAFE | android.util.Base64.NO_PADDING);
```

Most importantly for your use case is the `android.util.Base64.URL_SAFE` and  `android.util.Base64.NO_PADDING` flags.

Comment: Thanks alot Worked perfectly

Comment: Glad to help mate